# How can I handle SQL errors after $resource save method?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to save a language to db via AngularJS:

```
Languages.save(null,language,function(value, responseHeaders){
       toaster.pop('success', "Successful", language.name + " saved successfuly");
    }, function(response){
   //error callback
 });
```

Although response has status code of 500 because of duplicate entry, it goes to success callback. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) now to handle errors.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.23/docs/api/ng/service/$http) say that "A response status code between 200 and 299 is considered a success status." Anything else should be calling your error callback. I would double check and make sure it's actually sending the 500, though if you have access to the server you should catch the sql error and respond with a 400, since a duplicate save is an error on the submitter's part, not the server.

Comment: I am sure it is sending 500.